# Calculate Column width of longtabu and preserve format when using multicolumn

Tags: multicolumn, longtabu

I'm using the `longtabu` environment to create a table, the general look is almost how I want it, however I'm running into a few issues that mess with the formatting. Here's basically what I want to do:

[image]

As you can see the cells left and right of the `multicolumn` are not centered vertically anymore and I have no idea how to fix that. I had similar Issues before when using `makecell` in the table which I could fix by making sure that all columns had the `m` attribute to properly align. This does not seem to work here however.

Additionally I would like to be able to dynamically calculate the width  of the four combined columns instead of having to gauge the width manually, I am still too new to Latex to do that however so any help would be welcome!
Here's how I achieved this so far, could be I am making some unnecessary errors, still pretty new to tex ...

```
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth 
{@{}|X[-1,l,m]
|X[-1,l,m]
|X[l,m]
|X[-1,l,m]|
X[-1,l,m]|
X[-1,l,m]|
X[l,m]|>{\color{gray}}X[-1,c,m]| @{}} 
\tabucline[1pt]-
\everyrow{\tabucline[0.5pt]-}
\rowcolor{light-gray} Name & Options & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & Attributes & Ref\\ 
\tabucline[1pt]-
\endhead
Name goes here & available options & Description & . & . & . & . & . \\
& Description of Option & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{\rlap{\parbox[t]{6.8cm}
{Here is supposed to be a very long text that is shown across 
colums 3 to 6, combining 4 columns, however when combining columns 
here the cells left and right of this text are no longer vertically 
centered and I have to manually add the width of this box.}}} 
& more attributes & ... \\
& Desc. 2 & & & & & \makecell{centered\\attributes\\seem to\\work here} &...\\
\end{longtabu}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you have some special reason to use `tabu/longtabu` package? It is buggy ... it is better to use `xltabular` or `ltablex`. With both you will able to manage your target table design. btw, i will not verticaly centered cells' contents, to my taste is nicer to have them top aligned.

Comment: I am still pretty new to TeX in general, so when I was looking for a package to do what I wanted to do I stumbled on `tabu/longtabu` and it seemed to have what I wanted (mostly the X columns being able to stretch those). I like the look of the centered cells but as you said, personal preference ;)

Comment: Read the readme and the issue list here before using tabu: https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu/

Comment: Ah okay, I wasn't aware of the status of `tabu`. I got what I wanted working with `xltabular` as was suggested, and I'm pretty happy with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your table using the `xltabular` package instead of `longtabu` as already recommended [by Zarko in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498889/calculate-column-width-of-longtabu-and-preserve-format-when-using-multicolumn/498893#comment1259990_498889):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{RGB}{130,130,130}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|l|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|l|l|l|l|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor{light-gray} Name & Options & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & Attributes & \\ \hline
Name goes here & available options & Description & . & . & . & . & . \\ 
\hline
& Description of Option & \multicolumn{4}{m{5cm}|}{{Here is supposed to be a very long text that is shown across colums 3 to 6, combining 4 columns, however when combining columns here the cells left and right of this text are no longer vertically centered and I have to manually add the width of this box.}} 
& more attributes & ... \\
\hline
& Desc. 2 & & & & & centered attributes seem to work here &...\\
\hline
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does look like it would solve the problem of the vertical alignment! I do however not really know `xltabular`, I was using `tabu/longtabu` because it allowed the table to span several pages, have the top row repeat on every page and automatically put `\hline` after every row.

Comment: @Panicmode: The `xltabular` package combines the features of the `tabularx` package (`X` type columns)  and the `longtable` package (tables that can span multiple pages and allow for repeated table headers,...).

Comment: Thanks for the info! I wasnt aware that the header was a `longtable` feature as opposed to `tabu`. I ran into the issue that `rowcolor` would leave a gap when defining the head as `makecell` but that was solvable with `colorbox` so that worked out too, thanks for the help.